# Android Notifications empty when app is closed

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

I have working notifications(with service) on my app and it works ok when the app is in onPause, but when I close the app, the notification text/title is null and the notification appear, but with no title/body.

[image]

Here is the Notification builder code:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flag, int startId)
{
    super.onStartCommand(intent , flag, startId);

    String titleS = Utils.Title;
    String bodyS = Utils.Body;

    Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle(titleS);
    builder.setContentText(bodyS);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

It is obvious that the titleS and bodyS is null when the app is closed and that is why the notification appear without any information.

My question is what is the correct way to save/display this data into notification when my app is closed ?

Answer (score 0):

I set my alarmintent putExtra (forgot completly about this)

```
alarmIntent.putExtra("title" , Title);
alarmIntent.putExtra("body" , Body);
```

And then in my Broadcast reciever, onReceive I get those String with:

```
String titleS = intent.getStringExtra("title");
String bodyS = intent.getStringExtra("body");
```

It`s working fine now.